# Volley response JSON Exception: Unterminated array at character

Tags: json, exception, android-volley

I use Volley to get data from Xtream server.
It normally works, but when it sends certain requests, Volley returns an unterminated array which occurs a JSONException.
I had some investigation on it, and found that those cases are when the server returns relatively large amount of data, and that the response string emits some symbols such as comma, bracket etc.

try {
    ...
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);
    ...
} catch(JSONException e) {}

How can I pretreat the variable "data" so the above statement won't return any Exception?
Thank you for your reply in advance.